# Including .pgf plots with sans serif fonts in a serif document

Tags: tikz-pgf, greek, sans-serif, mathpazo, matplotlib

I am creating the plots and figures for my thesis using `matplotlib` and save them as `.pgf` files that I include using

```latex
\begin{figure}
    \input{myfigure.pgf}
    \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}
```

which by default typesets all math and labels in the figure using the same fonts as in the document. But I want my plots and figures to use sans serif fonts while using palatino as the main document font.

So far I tried the following:
Add `mpl.rcParams["font.family"] = "sans-serif"` to the plot generation code to get all the non-math text typeset in a sans serif font and to get the math in a sans serif font I used the `sansmath` package as follows:

```latex
% preamble
\usepackage{sansmath}
% more preamble
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{sansmath}
    \input{myfigure.pgf}
    \end{sansmath}
    \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This works well for all labels and math in the figure *except* for greek letters. Using the option `\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}` also doesn't help.

Does anyone have a good solution to include pgf files with all sans-serif fonts? Preferably a solution that does not require changing the matplotlib rcParams, because I might want to reuse
the figures elsewhere with different formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution that works well enough. Basically, the main problem was that the math fonts don't obey the surrounding font family. I.e. math that is in a paragraph typeset in sans-serif font is not typeset in sans-serif. So one needs to make sure, that math is also properly typeset in a sans family font, by adding the following to the preamble:

```latex
\DeclareMathVersion{sans}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{sans}{OT1}{kurierm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sans}{OML}{kurier}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{sans}{OMS}{kurier}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{sans}{OT1}{kurier}{m}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{sans}{OT1}{kurier}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{sans}{OT1}{kurier}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{sans}{OMX}{kurier}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathVersion{boldsans}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{boldsans}{OT1}{kurierm}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{boldsans}{OML}{kurier}{b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{boldsans}{OMS}{kurier}{b}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{boldsans}{OT1}{kurier}{b}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{boldsans}{OT1}{kurier}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{boldsans}{OT1}{kurier}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{boldsans}{OMX}{kurier}{bx}{n}

\newif\IfInSansMode
\let\oldsf\sffamily
\renewcommand*{\sffamily}{\oldsf\mathversion{sans}\InSansModetrue}
\let\oldmd\mdseries
\renewcommand*{\mdseries}{\oldmd\IfInSansMode\mathversion{sans}\fi\relax}
\let\oldbf\bfseries
\renewcommand*{\bfseries}{\oldbf\IfInSansMode\mathversion{boldsans}\else%
   \mathversion{bold}\fi\relax}
\let\oldnorm\normalfont
\renewcommand*{\normalfont}{\oldnorm\InSansModefalse\mathversion{normal}}
\let\oldrm\rmfamily
\renewcommand*{\rmfamily}{\oldrm\InSansModefalse\mathversion{normal}}
```

and keeping the `mpl.rcParams["font.family"] = "sans-serif"` to make the plots all sans-serif.